# How to animate 2 or more elements at the same time using GreenSock?

Tags: jquery, gsap

I'd like to animate two different elements at once using Green Sock. How do I modify the below code so that they execute the exact animation at the same time and not one after another?

```
tlProject = new TimelineMax({});    

tlProject.from($animated_bowl, 2, {opacity: 0, scale: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut})
    .from($animated_bowl_shadow, 2, {opacity: 0, scale: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`.from()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/from/), [`.to()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/to/) and [`.fromTo()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/fromTo/) methods of [`TimelineMax`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/) can take an additional `position` parameter that can control the placement of your tweens.

For your specific case, you only need to tell each tween to start at 0 (zero).

```
tlProject = new TimelineMax();
tlProject.from($animated_bowl, 2, {opacity: 0, scale: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut}, 0)
    .from($animated_bowl_shadow, 2, {opacity: 0, scale: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut}, 0);
```

Check out this awesome tutorial to get a better understanding of how the `position` parameter works and all that you can do with it: https://greensock.com/position-parameter.

Another option is to pass both elements at once, as the `target`

```
tlProject = new TimelineMax();
tlProject.from([$animated_bowl, $animated_bowl_shadow], 2, {opacity: 0, scale: 0, ease: Bounce.easeOut});
```